# The value of `this`

Tags: javascript

I am learning JavaScript from the book "The Good Parts" and on Page `33`, the author has written this piece of code:

```
Function.prototype.method = function (name, func) {
    this.prototype[name] = func;
    return this;
}
```

What does `this` represent in this function?

Comment: The object which is calling `method`.

Comment: @Tushar can we use this in properties ?

Comment: @Mahi Yes, we can use `this` for properties as well as methods.

Comment: @Tushar how . ?? can i write `obj={pro:this}` ??

Comment: @Tushar then property value is always window object ??

Comment: @Mahi I misunderstood your question. We cannot use this like that, that'll throw syntax error.

Comment: @Tushar i also thought like that . but i am getting no error . try this in console. `var obj={
 1:this
}`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130107/discussion-between-mahi-and-tushar).